# PHP : Get or search values in_array from my variable and display it

Tags: php, arrays

I have array I'm checking if my variable has a value in that array. Also, get the same value as well. I need  to add condition first, like for example if the variable 25 has a same value in my array $arr return true and display the array value array`(2=>25)`

```
$variable = 25;
$arr = array(1=>26, 2=>25 ,3 => 30 ,4 => 31, 5 => 32);

if(in_array($variable , $arr)){

   //get the array value that have in array and display that array and preserve the key
   //print_r($arr) -> 25

}
```

Comment: so what exactly is your question?

Comment: do you are looking something like this:- https://eval.in/646267   OR may be this:- https://eval.in/646268

Comment: You already have the value its called `$variable`

Comment: I mean search the value of variable into that array, If true, then display the 2=>25. Example if 25 has a value in array $arr , true. Then display 2=>25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said:-

*I mean search the value of variable into that array, If true, then display the 2=>25. Example if 25 has a value in array $arr , true. Then display 2=>25*

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php

$variable = 25;
$arr = array(1=>26, 2=>25 ,3 => 30 ,4 => 31, 5 => 32);


$key = array_search($variable,$arr); // search the value and return the key
echo $key .'=>'.$arr[$key]; // echo both key and value based on key
```

output:-https://eval.in/646272

Note:- if two values are identical in array and you are searching for that value,then the above code will give only first match not second-one